# How can I conditional format color scale row-by-row in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have the following data:

```
target_gene A   B   C   D
LETMD1  2.479   1.784   2.446   2.172
HHEX    0.343   0.010   0.313   0.166
CLNK    0.000   0.090   0.000   0.000
TAL1    0.000   0.000   0.041   0.000
```

And with Microsoft Excel, I manually **Conditional Format -> Color scale**

[image]

the content row-by-row, with the following result

[image]

In reality, I have a few thousand of rows to process. How 
can I do that conveniently (or programmatically) in Excel?

I'm using MS Excel v15.31 for Macintosh.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro for 1 line and then manually adding a FOR loop around it?

Comment: In case you don't want to use Macros: Do you need the full color spectrum, or would highlighting only the min/max be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Full-color spectrum.

Comment: Then use K.David solution:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help of the macro recorder, you can just place this in a `For...Next` loop

```
Sub formatRows()

    Dim r As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Rows(r)
                .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
                    xlConditionValueLowestValue
                With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
                    .Color = 13011546
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
                    xlConditionValuePercentile
                .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
                With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
                    .Color = 16776444
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
                    xlConditionValueHighestValue
                With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
                    .Color = 7039480
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End With
        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @K.Davis Can you give example for workable ForNext loop construct to run for the function you made? (e.g. how to pass variable to your function in the loop). I know nothing of VBA.

Comment: @K.Davis how can the function now which column and row to process in the loop? Like example with loop will really help.

Comment: It’s already in a loop. `For r = 1 to ...` is a *For…Next* loop. `r` is the row number. Then you’re using a `With Rows(r)` statement to process each row until the end of your document

Comment: @K.Davis So you're saying your code is ready to use for all rows in my data?

Comment: @scamander Yes it is :).. But if your sheet to run it on is not (1), then you should change that line: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` and replace 1 with whatever sheet it is, or use the name `("Sheet1")`.